# Error making request with curl_error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, easyphp

I upgraded from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 (easyphp) and i now got the following  error:

```
Exception: TestCaseCtrlSignUp -> testSignUp -> Unexpected PHP error [Error making request with curl_error: error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol] severity [256] in [C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.0\www\workspace\CPS\lib\campain_monitor\class\transport.php line 132]
Failed with code 0
```

Here is the transport.php file :

```
define('CS_REST_GET', 'GET');
define('CS_REST_POST', 'POST');
define('CS_REST_PUT', 'PUT');
define('CS_REST_DELETE', 'DELETE');
define('CS_REST_SOCKET_TIMEOUT', 1);

function CS_REST_TRANSPORT_get_available($requires_ssl, $log) {
    if(function_exists('curl_init') && function_exists('curl_exec')) {
        return new CS_REST_CurlTransport($log);
    } else if(CS_REST_TRANSPORT_can_use_raw_socket($requires_ssl)) {
        return new CS_REST_SocketTransport($log);
    } else { 
        $log->log_message('No transport is available', __FUNCTION__, CS_REST_LOG_ERROR);
        trigger_error('No transport is available.'.
            ($requires_ssl ? ' Try using non-secure (http) mode or ' : ' Please ').
            'ensure the cURL extension is loaded', E_USER_ERROR);
    }    
}
function CS_REST_TRANSPORT_can_use_raw_socket($requires_ssl) {
    if(function_exists('fsockopen')) {
        if($requires_ssl) {
            return extension_loaded('openssl');
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}   
class CS_REST_BaseTransport {

    var $_log;

    function CS_REST_BaseTransport($log) {
        $this->_log = $log;
    }

    function split_and_inflate($response, $may_be_compressed) {        
        $ra = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response);

        $result = array_pop($ra);
        $headers = array_pop($ra);

        if($may_be_compressed && preg_match('/^Content-Encoding:\s+gzip\s+$/im', $headers)) {        
            $original_length = strlen($response);
            $result = gzinflate(substr($result, 10, -8));

            $this->_log->log_message('Inflated gzipped response: '.$original_length.' bytes ->'.
                strlen($result).' bytes', get_class(), CS_REST_LOG_VERBOSE);
        }

        return array($headers, $result); 
    }
}
/**
 * Provide HTTP request functionality via cURL extensions
 *
 * @author tobyb
 * @since 1.0
 */
class CS_REST_CurlTransport extends CS_REST_BaseTransport {

    var $_curl_zlib;

    function CS_REST_CurlTransport($log) {
        $this->CS_REST_BaseTransport($log);

        $curl_version = curl_version();
        $this->_curl_zlib = isset($curl_version['libz_version']);
    }

    /**
     * @return string The type of transport used
     */
    function get_type() {
        return 'cURL';
    }

    function make_call($call_options) {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $call_options['route']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $call_options['credentials']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $call_options['userAgent']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: '.$call_options['contentType']));

        $headers = array();
        $inflate_response = false;
        if($this->_curl_zlib) {
            $this->_log->log_message('curl+zlib support available. Requesting gzipped response.',
                get_class($this), CS_REST_LOG_VERBOSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
        } else if(function_exists('gzinflate')) {
            $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip';
            $inflate_response = true;
        }

        if($call_options['protocol'] === 'https') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__).'/GoDaddyClass2CA.crt');
        }

        switch($call_options['method']) {
            case CS_REST_PUT:
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, CS_REST_PUT);
                $headers[] = 'Content-Length: '.strlen($call_options['data']);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $call_options['data']);
                break;
            case CS_REST_POST:
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $call_options['data']);
                break;
            case CS_REST_DELETE:
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, CS_REST_DELETE);
                break;
        }

        if(count($headers) > 0) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        }

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        if(!$response && $response !== '') {
            $this->_log->log_message('Error making request with curl_error: '.curl_errno($ch),
                get_class($this), CS_REST_LOG_ERROR);
            trigger_error('Error making request with curl_error: '.curl_error($ch), E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        list( $headers, $result ) = $this->split_and_inflate($response, $inflate_response);

        $this->_log->log_message('API Call Info for '.$call_options['method'].' '.
        curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL).': '.curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD).
            ' bytes uploaded. '.curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD).' bytes downloaded'.
            ' Total time (seconds): '.curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME), 
        get_class($this), CS_REST_LOG_VERBOSE);

        $result = array(
            'code' => curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE),
            'response' => $result
        );

        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
}

class CS_REST_SocketWrapper {
    var $socket;

    function open($domain, $port) {
        $this->socket = fsockopen($domain, $port, $errno, $errstr, CS_REST_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

        if(!$this->socket) {
            die('Error making request with '.$errno.': '.$errstr);
            return false;
        } else if(function_exists('stream_set_timeout')) {
            stream_set_timeout($this->socket, CS_REST_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function write($data) {
        fwrite($this->socket, $data);
    }

    function read() {
        ob_start();
        fpassthru($this->socket);

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    function close() {
        fclose($this->socket);
    }
}

class CS_REST_SocketTransport extends CS_REST_BaseTransport {

    var $_socket_wrapper;

    function CS_REST_SocketTransport($log, $socket_wrapper = NULL) {
        $this->CS_REST_BaseTransport($log);

        if(is_null($socket_wrapper)) {
            $socket_wrapper = new CS_REST_SocketWrapper();
        }

        $this->_socket_wrapper = $socket_wrapper;
    }

    /**
     * @return string The type of transport used
     */
    function get_type() {
        return 'Socket';
    }

    function make_call($call_options) {
        $start_host = strpos($call_options['route'], $call_options['host']);
        $host_len = strlen($call_options['host']);

        $domain = substr($call_options['route'], $start_host, $host_len);
        $host = $domain;
        $path = substr($call_options['route'], $start_host + $host_len);
        $protocol = substr($call_options['route'], 0, $start_host);
        $port = 80;

        $this->_log->log_message('Creating socket to '.$domain.' over '.$protocol.' for request to '.$path,
            get_class($this), CS_REST_LOG_VERBOSE);

        if($protocol === 'https://') {
            $domain = 'ssl://'.$domain;
            $port = 443;
        }

        if($this->_socket_wrapper->open($domain, $port)) {
            $inflate_response = function_exists('gzinflate');

            $request = $this->_build_request($call_options, $host, $path, $inflate_response);
            $this->_log->log_message('Sending <pre>'.$request.'</pre> down the socket',
            get_class($this), CS_REST_LOG_VERBOSE);

            $this->_socket_wrapper->write($request);
            $response = $this->_socket_wrapper->read();
            $this->_socket_wrapper->close();

            $this->_log->log_message('API Call Info for '.$call_options['method'].' '.
            $call_options['route'].': '.strlen($request).
                ' bytes uploaded. '.strlen($response).' bytes downloaded', 
            get_class($this), CS_REST_LOG_VERBOSE);

            list( $headers, $result ) = $this->split_and_inflate($response, $inflate_response);

            $this->_log->log_message('Received headers <pre>'.$headers.'</pre>',
                get_class($this), CS_REST_LOG_VERBOSE);

            return array(
                'code' => $this->_get_status_code($headers),
                'response' => trim($result)
            );
        }
    }

    function _get_status_code($headers) {
        if (preg_match('%^\s*HTTP/1\.1 (?P<code>\d{3})%', $headers, $regs)) {
            $this->_log->log_message('Got HTTP Status Code: '.$regs['code'],
            get_class($this), CS_REST_LOG_VERBOSE);
            return $regs['code'];
        }

        $this->_log->log_message('Failed to get HTTP status code from request headers <pre>'.$headers.'</pre>',
            get_class($this), CS_REST_LOG_ERROR);
        trigger_error('Failed to get HTTP status code from request', E_USER_ERROR);        
    }

    function _build_request($call_options, $host, $path, $accept_gzip) {
        $request =
$call_options['method'].' '.$path." HTTP/1.1\n".
'Host: '.$host."\n".
'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($call_options['credentials'])."\n".
'User-Agent: '.$call_options['userAgent']."\n".
"Connection: Close\n".
'Content-Type: '.$call_options['contentType']."\n";

        if($accept_gzip) {
            $request .=
"Accept-Encoding: gzip\n";           
        }

        if(isset($call_options['data'])) {
            $request .=
'Content-Length: '.strlen($call_options['data'])."\n\n".
$call_options['data'];
        }

        return $request."\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you upgrade PHP manually or did you upgrade EasyPHP?

Comment: easyphp, but i checked php.ini and the curl ext is activated, i'll precise easyphp in my question (good point) ;)

Comment: Yes curl is activated, but problem is with one of the protocols. It's not supported. So curl works, but not all protocols are supported.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940039/php-with-curl-ssl-error-unsupported-protocol - espeically the comment. This is likely to be related to the version of openssl that has been used when compiling the easyphp package. I suggest you report that on the EasyPHP website as well.

Comment: Do you know how to change the openssl version used by EasyPHP?

Comment: No, that's why I suggested you should report the problem with the project itself. They should know (hopefully) / have more control over the binaries. Also I *can* imagine other users of easyphp might have a similar issue. I tag your question here a bit. Your curl error number is: 14077102

Comment: yes i already did that as well, first thing ;) Thanks for your help hakra :)

Comment: You should cross-link both threads. Also enter the error number into google and read all you can find so far. The error is not much documented, so you might want to inspect the source-code of the PHP curl extension for that number to learn more and to find out what a corresponding openssl error code is/might be. That should help with trouble-shooting.